# TypeScript: Correct typing for a function that will return undefined if any of the parameters are undefined

Tags: typescript, types

I am stuck on a problem to give a function the correct type.

The allDefined function will return undefined, if any of the provided parameters are undefined.
If all parameters are defined, it will return the parameters as an array.

```js
/**
 * will return undefined if some value is undefined, otherwise the array of parameters
 * @param parameters the parameters to check for undefined
 * @returns undefined if some value is undefined, otherwise the array of parameters
 */
export function allDefined<T extends readonly any[]>(...parameters: T): T | undefined {
    if(parameters.some((p) => p === undefined)) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

How can i write the type, so that the correct return type is inferred?

```js
allDefined(1,2,3) // then the result type is [number, number, number]
allDefined(1,2,undefined) // then the result type is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a conditional type for the return. Unfortunately, in the body of the function we'll need to use a type assertion on what we return, so to keep things brief let's define a type alias for the return type:

```typescript
type AllDefinedReturnType<T extends readonly any[]> =
    undefined extends T[number] ? undefined : T;
```

Then applying it to your function:

```typescript
/**
 * will return undefined if some value is undefined, otherwise the array of parameters
 * @param parameters the parameters to check for undefined
 * @returns undefined if some value is undefined, otherwise the array of parameters
 */
export function allDefined<T extends readonly any[]>(
    ...parameters: T
): AllDefinedReturnType<T> {
    if (parameters.some((p) => p === undefined)) {
        return undefined as AllDefinedReturnType<T>;
    }
    return parameters as AllDefinedReturnType<T>;
}
```

Usage examples:

```typescript
const ex1 = allDefined(1, 2, 3);
//    ^? const ex1: [number, number, number]
const ex2 = allDefined(1, 2, undefined);
//    ^? const ex2: undefined
const ex3 = allDefined(1, "two", true);
//    ^? const ex3: [number, string, boolean]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAIhAZgSwHYQCYCULACuAThgCrgQA8ZUEAHsBBtgM5TEQCG2A9hnBBQuGEAG0AugD4oAXgBQUJVEItUmHHUbM2UMmIyEAtgCMIxCVAD8KteizYoALj0BuefID0AKm+LvUADuaAgcBCQYttjqDlBoKFCsvEbQAG5ccITQaOyq0fY4ADRQvMAAFubBrNDl0FzExFxCvAlg9VwpTMSs-lAAAm2NRlCDHQTm7LUj7Z0TUMC8UADGFUsA1lAovMRRMTi9fZxEpLl2Go7xiclpGVlxp-nnxaUVxFU1FcINTSWtM+PdfyeeQMMDbYCbVRLYBofjCBDIArYGhaJgsdicHj8QTCUSSKQACkUygAdGTRrNui4yPIAJQueBIPZ4cKkCiQGgyADexKUlwJFIBrBJSRSBIFtLkMjAclksl2SNpkp5ylVYWOkTyzOE7EZiPO+A17OoZCk7lVAF9eeqItMhkKdbAEczDRFjZz3Fb5Et+KwIQwAIxyeFMpEEgPFABMxQAzLT3J5PKqAHpWb2+-30SPBjKh87hqPFLWKhNJ5Sp9MYP1aGM551hiNQABEwECvCbxWAxCy8a8ZaUFaAA)

Comment: You can avoid the two (ugly) redundant assertions by using an overload: https://tsplay.dev/wE713m

Comment: @vr. - True, the rules for the return values of overload implementations are really loose. Personally I prefer the assertions, but horses for courses. :-)